# How to protect my application ESRI FGDB data from authorized access using other applications?

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

I have ArcObjects app which uses file geodatabase for storing data and performing CRUD operations. This file geodatabase  needs to be protected from reading data in other applications such as ArcMap, Civil 3d and other 3rd party's. 
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean 'unauthorized access'? Can you put it on a network share where only authorized users have permissions to access it?

Comment: I meant some kind of protection(may be transparent encryption) that only my software is allowed to perform CRUD operations, without a matter where this FGDB is located.